# UI Testing on iOS, Setting a custom `timeoutDuration` for XCTestCase specially for XCUIApplication.launch()

Tags: travis-ci, xctest

When running UI tests on a CI (like Travis), often times, the box is too busy (or too underpowered) to launch the application very fast.
It looks like XCTest expects the lunch to take very short (less than 2.5 seconds?) and `XCUIApplication().launch()` fails with a timeout error.

Is there a way to set custom timeout durations for this? 
There is a private `timeoutDuration` property on the `XCTestCase`, but it is private. I tried to set it using `objc_setAssociatedObject` but didn't work (maybe I am doing it wrong).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to add a small "sleep" right after `XCUIApplication().launch()`? We heard that's one of the possible solutions. You can find other options here too: https://bitrise-io.github.io/devcenter/ios/known-xcode-issues/#possible-solutions

Comment: Thanks @ViktorBenei , yes I actually ended up adding rather large sleeps (10 seconds if I remember) here and there, it reduced but not completely solve the problem. It was a while ago (almost a year! wow, life passes).

Comment: Hopefully this will be improved in Xcode 8, these issues crippled the otherwise awesome UI testing feature in Xcode 7..